# C# Regular expression: how to get one of two texts with condition?

Tags: c#

I've something like that "`[sex:he|she] took the dog for a walk`"
after I get the gender from the user for example (1 for male 2 for female)
If the gender is male then I want the text to be "he took the dog for a walk" 
How can I do that ?

All i have till now is I can get value using group

```
Regex r = new Regex("^(?<name>\\w+):(?<value>\\w+)");
Match m = r.Match("Section1:119900"); 

Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Value); 
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Yet i can't add brackets to it or using condition

Comment: What you have tried for it?

Comment: [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: All i have till now is I can get value using group               Regex r = new Regex("^(?<name>\\w+):(?<value>\\w+)");
Match m = r.Match("Section1:119900");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["value"].Value);    yet i can't add brackets to it or using condition

Comment: @Mark Replace will not help me as the value can be changed yet still can't condition

Comment: why don't you just append the users choice to the string " took the dog for a walk"? This all seems to be unnecessary post-processing **EDIT**: or just the letter "s" to the beginning of the string if its for a female

Comment: @Sayse this is just an example , the real text will be in another language.

Comment: I'm not sure what difference that makes? It seems to me like you should be able to build this string up after getting the users choice instead of editing an existing string

Comment: @Sayse the text is in xml file that is already written. later i get the text by providing the key.

Comment: Then as Mark says, replace `[sex:he|she]` with the users choice (no need for regex)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but some of you seem to have misunderstood the point. If the intention is to translate the string, it would be a mistake to translate "{0} took the dog for a walk" and then add the translated 'He' or 'She'. Not all languages have personal pronouns, the translator might choose to change the sentence by removing the gender specific words, or even adding other gender specific words/phrases.  (Additionally I assume that the 'sex' example is one of numerous categories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture each value and use the MatchEvaluator to process the groups.

```
string inputString = "[sex:he|she] took the dog with [sex:him|her]";
string result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\[(?<name>[^:]+):(?<value1>[^\|]+)\|(?<value2>[^\]]+)\]", Evaluator);
```

And the evaluator could replace any group with the appropriate response:

```
private string Evaluator(Match match)
{
    if (match.Groups["name"].Value == "sex")
    {
        if (m_IsMale)
        {
            return match.Groups["value1"].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return match.Groups["value2"].Value;
        }
    }
    // No replacement, return the original value.
    return match.Value;
}
```

The above results in either

```
he took the dog with him
```

or

```
she took the dog with her
```